# Handling the restart with apache beam debezium application

Tags: apache-beam, debezium

In my current scenario, I have an Apache Beam application that employs Debezium for capturing changes in data. Unlike the typical integration with Kafka, I am not using it in conjunction with Kafka. However, I've encountered a challenge related to restarting the application. Whenever I restart the application, it retrieves all the data from the very beginning. My objective is to ensure that the application resumes consuming data from where it left off before the restart. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to achieve this. Here is the structure of my application:

```
public class PipelineTest {
private static final DebeziumIO.ConnectorConfiguration mySqlConnectorConfig = DebeziumIO.ConnectorConfiguration
.create()
.withUsername("xxxxxxxx")
.withPassword("xxxxxxxx")
.withHostName("localhost")
.withPort("5432")
.withConnectorClass(PostgresConnector.class)
.withConnectionProperty("database.dbname", "xxxxxxxx")
.withConnectionProperty("database.server.id", "xxxxxxxx")
.withConnectionProperty("database.server.name", "xxxxxxxx")
.withConnectionProperty("plugin.name", "pgoutput")
.withConnectionProperty("slot.name", "debezium5")
.withConnectionProperty("table.include.list", "public.table1");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.setRunner(org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.class); // Set the Direct Runner
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    System.out.println("Pipeline starting...");

    PCollection<String> records = pipeline
            .apply(DebeziumIO.<String>read()
                    .withConnectorConfiguration(mySqlConnectorConfig)
                    .withFormatFunction(sourceRecord ->
                         sourceRecord.value().toString())
                    .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
            );

    records.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            System.out.println("Pipeline starting 3..." + c.element());
        }
    }));

    System.out.println("Pipeline ending...");

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
}
```

it seems like replication slot related following values are not changing with the at all, the query =>[ SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots; ]
catalog_xmin
restart_lsn
confirmed_flush_lsn

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to achieve this..

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to achieve this